# VBA addindent propert

Tags: vba

Does anyone know what this does as I have used the example in the help section to alter a cell value commenting out the addindent part and leaving it in and the result is the same or appears to be. The code given is,

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
  . HorizontalAlignment = xlhalig distributed
  .AddIndent = True
End With
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you reset the cell contents/style before you ran the code for the second time?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51411481/edit) to include more information.

Answer (score -1):

I actually had a column of numbers in A so changed the cell ref to the next row before running to compare.

A1 both lines of code ran
A2 just the first
A3 just the second.

Could it be that excel already has the prop switched to true by default which is why no change visible?

Comment: This isn't an answer. Instead, it belongs either as a comment or as an edit to your question.